# Understanding Linearization

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this very simple question about linearization here which says:

''If we use the linearization of $f(x) = (2−x)^\frac{1}{5}$ at $a = 1$, then $(1.05)^\frac{1}{5}$ is approximately equal to

$$a) 0.99$$
$$b) 1.005$$
$$c) 1.01$$
$$d) 1.09$$
$$e) 1.1$$
$$f) \text {None of the above}$$''

I got the formula for my linearization formula which is $L(x)=\frac{6}{5}-\frac{x}{5}$ and I believe that is correct.

What number do I substitute for $x$ though? I thought I would plug in $x=0.05$ for my formula but I don't get anywhere near the actual value if I do that. I'm a little confused about that. What value of x would I plug in?

Comment: You need $0.95$. Think about it: you need $2-x=1.05$ and surely $x$ must be $0.95$ not $0.05$

Comment: The question tripped me up because it said to linearize around a=1 so I thought I would have to go up by 0.05 to get to 1.05.

Comment: @mfl No. He want's to approximate the value at $0.95$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer that was just deleted said... we were looking for the value at .95 so we can get $(1.05)^{\frac{1}{5}}$ and so we plug in .95 to your already correct linearization. Note we are not asked to approximate at 1.05 we are asked to approximate $(1.05)^{\frac{1}{5}}$

Comment: I see. So even though it asks me to linearize around a=1, I still plug in 0..95 to get 1.05 and not 0.05 because the a just tells me the point I approximate at. It doesn't tell me what number I plug in relative to a to get 1.05. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Yeah that confused me too at first, because this question asked you approximate a value and not at a value like it usually does. See what confused me was that I thought it was asking to approximate at 1.05. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that's what got me too. Yeah that makes sense. Thanks a lot.